# AngularJS $http service - Best practice for compound URIs

Tags: angularjs, rest, http, uri

I need to create a service for my "customer users". My API Endpoint it's `/api/v1/customer/:id_customer/users` with `GET/POST/PUT/DELETE` methods.

Now, in my AngularJS code I have a service which is the interface between my AngularJS `controllers` and the `$http` service like this:

```
module.exports = function ($http) {
    var service = {};
    var _mainUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/api/v1/customer/';

    service.get = function (id) {
        return $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: _mainUrl + id
        });
    };

    service.save = function (model) {
        return $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: _mainUrl,
            data: model
        });
    };

    return service;
};
```

Now, in my "customer users" service I need the `:id_customer` to be passed to my service. So, which would be a nice approach? Should I pass the :id_customer to every method, like:

```
module.exports = function ($http) {
    var service = {};
    var _mainUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/api/v1/customer/';
    var _tailUrl = '/user/';

    service.get = function (id_customer, id) {
        return $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: _mainUrl + id_customer + _tailUrl + id
        });
    };

    return service;
};
```

Or maybe should I have a `"setter"` and call it before make any call, like:

```
module.exports = function ($http) {
    var service = {};
    var _mainUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/api/v1/customer/';
    var _idCustomer = '';
    var _tailUrl = '/user/';

    service.get = function (id) {
        return $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: _mainUrl + _idCustomer + _tailUrl + id
        });
    };

    service.setCustomer = function (id_customer) {
        _idCustomer = id_customer;
    }

    return service;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first approach is better -- pass `id_customer` and `id_user` to one method.

There are several reasons:

1. **Coupling**. By "have a 'setter' and call it before make any call", this 'setter' method and its corresponding 'getter' method is very tightly coupled -- 'getter' method depends on its 'setter', which should be avoided. Methods should have high cohesion and low coupling. Please refer to [Coupling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_%28computer_programming%29) for more information.
2. **Maintenance problem**. As 'setter' should be called before 'getter', this rule needs to be documented, and deliver to every new programmer in the project. However, people forget things. Even experienced developer may forget this rule at some time. If programmer invokes 'getter' but forget to 'set' first, error happens. It's better to prevent error by coding design, not by people training.
3. **Inconsistent state**. As 'get-customer', 'get-customer-users' and 'set-customer' are all in the same service, it is possible that in some cases, customer A is set, but later when 'get-customer' or 'get-customer-users' is invoked, another customer's data is returned -- this can be prevented by strictly following "call setter *right before* any getter invokation" rule, but again, this rule depends on developer's training and habit.